# Apache: ExpiresByType per directory?

Tags: .htaccess, directory, apache-2.2

I have a folder with javascript files that should expire faster than the normal scripts.

Is it possible to let files expire per directory using Apache 2 other than .htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you can put these directives into a `<Directory>` tag in your apache configuration: [mod_expires#ExpiresActive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresactive)

For example like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/js/expire_fast>
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```